# AMPscript If not empty Marketing Cloud If else

Tags: salesforce, ampscript

How should I structure this AMPscript to display 1 value if empty and other if not?

```
%%[ 

/*Set Dynamic Image URL for Hours Field */
IF not empty (@Business_Hours__c ) THEN
  SET @HoursImgURL = "URL1" 
ELSE 
  SET @HoursImgURL = "URL2"
ENDIF

]%%
```

or should I use :

```
IF Business_Hours__c == NULL THEN?
```

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Comment: How and where are you setting `@business_hours__c`?

Comment: This value is populated in my Data Extension (which is sendable)

Answer (score 1):

The IF statement above looks fine in that it will set @HoursImgURL to "URL1" when @Business_Hours__c is not empty or "URL2" otherwise. To display that value, you would then include something like the below:

```
%%=v(@HoursImgURL)=%%
```

For example, if using within HTML, it could look like this:

```
<div><img src="%%=v(@HoursImgURL)=%%" /></div>
```